# RewriteRule without absolute path

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to make this url point to another url in the same directory
but I can't get it to work without giving the absolute url.

I want this url
http://www.mysite.com/path/file/

To point to:
http://www.mysite.com/path/file.php

I have this:
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /path/$1.php

I want this:
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ $1.php

So it should automatically infer that the url should point to a file with the same name in the same directory. Is it possible?

Comment: I can't test at the moment, but wouldn't it work if you just changed it into ``RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php``?